# Display multiple ads Between post

Tags: wordpress, adsense

For multiple ads on post
I have implemented first code and it perfectly work. But iam not good at coding so can you tell me how to show multiple ads? This second code how to implement it properly can you help me with it?
Also for multiple ads do i need to create second in article ads code? Or i can use the same ads code twice?

```
//Insert ads after third paragraph of post content.
 
add_filter( 'the_content', 'insert_post_ads' );
 
function insert_post_ads( $content ) {
     
    $ad_code = '<div>Insert your Ads code here</div>';
 
    if ( is_single() && ! is_admin() ) {
        return prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $ad_code, 3, $content );
    }
     
    return $content;
}
  
// Parent Function
  
function prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $insertion, $paragraph_id, $content ) 
{
    $closing_p = '</p>';
    $paragraphs = explode( $closing_p, $content );
    foreach ($paragraphs as $index => $paragraph) {
 
        if ( trim( $paragraph ) ) {
            $paragraphs[$index] .= $closing_p;
        }
 
        if ( $paragraph_id == $index + 1 ) {
            $paragraphs[$index] .= $insertion;
        }
    }
     
    return implode( '', $paragraphs );
}
```

And this second code:

```
$first_ad_code = ‘Ads code goes here’;
 
$second_ad_code = $first_ad_code;
 
if ( is_single() && ! is_admin() ) {
$content = prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $first_ad_code, 3, $content );
$content = prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $second_ad_code, 6, $content );
return $content;
}
return $content;
}
```

I have collected this two code from this blog: https://www.codefixup.com/wordpress-insert-ads-between-posts/

i have astra child theme. these code will be pasted on child theme function.php

Please just edit these code as a one pls.

Comment: Please just edit these code as a one pls. So basically you're asking for someone to just do this for you?

Comment: Why dont you use Adinserter wordpress plugin?

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. i didn't know about adinserter plugin before. thanks mate. i have already installed and using it